# Is streaming API to ChaCha20-Poly1305 possible or recommended against?

Tags: encryption, implementation, authenticated-encryption, chacha, poly1305

None of the implementations of ChaCha20-Poly1305 AEAD scheme I've seen so far provide a streaming API. Instead, ChaCha20-Poly1305 is presented as an inseparable combination, closely adhering to the pseudocode from the [section 2.8 of "ChaCha20 and Poly1305 for IETF Protocols"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539#section-2.8), which requires the plaintext message to be fully loaded into memory. I would prefer to avoid that in case the input becomes very large (but still finite and with a known size). (I know I could split the message up, but I want to avoid that, too)

I'm starting to wonder if it's at all possible to provide a streaming API to that scheme? If not, why?

Comment: Poly1305 must be computed over the entire message, it's not a streaming authenticator. It's normally easiest to make fixed-length packets, with sequence numbers, and authenticate those independently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not specific to this construction, but generally, you want to split the stream in smaller chunks, that are individually encrypted and authenticated.

If the encrypted stream doesn't have a valid authentication tag, this is not something you want to discover at the very end, after having decrypted terabytes of data.

Some precautions have to be taken when splitting a stream into chunks. Namely, you need to make sure that chunks haven't been reordered, removed, duplicated and you need a way to verify that the last chunk you read was meant to be the end of the stream.

The [encrypting a sequence or a set of dependent messages](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/encrypted-messages.html) page in the libsodium documentation provides some guidance for this, as well as [a streaming API using Chacha20-Poly1305](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretstream.html).